# Varchar datatype as primary key in in many-to-many relationship

Tags: sql-server

I have a table with a `varchar` datatype as the primary key. I'm trying to make a relationship to the junction table of this many-to-many relationship. I keep getting the error

> The ALTER TABLE statement conflicted with the foreign key constraint
>   *relationship name*.

I don't know what the deal is here. Since I have designated the field as a primary key and it was accepted, this means there are no dupes. Both the foreign key and the primary key are of the same datatype, with the same length. Neither one allows nulls. What else could the problem be?

[image: http://imgur.com/MlMSW]

Comment: Show your table structure please, as well as your query.

Comment: I haven't tried any queries, because it keeps on telling me there's a problem with the relationship :/

Comment: I mean your DDL statement - `ALTER TABLE...`

Comment: I used the data diagram tool in SSMS (new to SQL SERVER).

Comment: I know, I'm asking you to put the **CODE THAT GENERATED THE ERROR YOU POSTED**.  I'm not sure how much clearer I can be...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most likely, you have a value in your junction table that does not exist in the primary table, which prevents you from creating the foreign key relationship.

Try to find it with something like:

```
SELECT j.ICD_FK
    FROM ICD_Junction j
        LEFT JOIN ICD_text t
            ON j.ICD_FK = t.ICD_ID
    WHERE t.ICD_ID IS NULL;
```

Comment: Okay, that did return several different (repeated) values.  These are the values that aren't present in the primary table?

Answer (score 1):

Just because there are no nulls or duplicates does not mean that you're not violating a foreign key relationship.

I'm guessing that the FK column has values in it that do not exist in the PK column.  Check by using a LEFT OUT JOIN WHERE NULL.